# Calculate percentage contribution of a dynamic changing range

Tags: vba, excel

I am novice to excel vba. I have written much of the Vba code for my program. need help in writing code for the below situation.

I have column A with various codes, column B has specified value for the respective codes in the corresponding month (Dynamically range changes from month to month)

Finally the column C should return the percentage contribution of the particular code.

Since this is a monthly activity, i need to macro to run the same

```
COL A   COL B   COL C
4001    25      19%
4002    25      19%
4003    10       7%
4004    20      15%
4005    20      15%
4006    34      25%
```

4001, COLC = 25/134 = 18.66%

The column A and B range changes dynamically with the month

Comment: Formula in `C1`: `=B1/SUM(B:B)`

Comment: When you say `Dynamically range changes from month to month` do you mean that, for example, January could be in cells A2:C7, February in A8:C9, March in A10:C100... in which case how do you know which row the month starts and ends on?  Or if the data is overwritten - the two answers given will work as stated.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That is what exactly i mean. The row starts just below the header file, which is in Row 2 and last row varies from month to month. Now the column C formula should identify the last row of the CoL B and find the SUM. Then the sum must be divided by each value in COL B and copied to whole range till the last row

Comment: So the sheet has data for more than one month - how do you know when the next month starts?

Comment: I will do this exercise for every month. The data provided is only for one month. So the value starts from Row2 and ends till all the products lasts- which changes from month to month

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a macro to get this result;
use below formula in C2 and fill it until the end

```
=B2/SUM(B:B)
```